# Google Events API returning 401 error unauthorized_client

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api

I have created an application in laravel to sync my users calendar in my database with [incremental sync](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync#initial_full_sync) every thing working perfect when i am running it in my browser.

but its returning 401 unauthorized_client in my cron 100% same code implemented in both files.

```
        $client = $this->getGoogleClient();
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        }
        $gCalService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $optArr = array();
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $pageToken = NULL;
        $responceEvents = array();
        $synced = $emailSync->getGoogleSynced();
        if($synced != null)
            $optArr['syncToken'] = $synced->sync_token;

        do {
            if ($pageToken) {
                $optArr['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            try {
                $results = $gCalService->events->listEvents($calendarId,$optArr);
            }
            catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                return $msg;
            }
            if ($results->getItems()) {
                $responceEvents = array_merge($responceEvents, $results->getItems());
                $pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();
            }
        } while ($pageToken);
```

`$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());`

returning below error

```
Array
(
    [error] => unauthorized_client
    [error_description] => Unauthorized
)
```

debugged code line by line `$client->getRefreshToken()` also contain value which i am passing here `$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);` exactly same code working fine in my browser file and not working in my cron.

Comment: How are you authenticating the cron job?

Comment: there is no authorization required for cron

Comment: authorization is always required in order to access private user data even in cron

Answer (score 0):

> 401 unauthorized_client

Means that your code has not been authorized.  If you want to access private user data you will need to be logged in. Your code needs an access token in order to access the Google api.

What you should be doing is authorizing your code once using Oauth2 in a browser save the refresh token someplace and have the cron job read the refresh token and request a new access token before it runs.

Assuming that you own the account you are trying to insert into you may also want to consider using a service account.

**Refresh token**

If you are storing the refresh token in the database you must assign it to your client first before running your code here i am doing that with a refresh token stored in a session variable.

```
$client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
```

Comment: I have every thing saved in database same code working exactly i want it to work but when adding that code in cron it stoped working.

Comment: Because cron is not reading your refresh token or getting a new access token.  Have it write it out to a file for you so you can see it.   please post the rest of your code where  is $client->getRefreshToken() set?

Comment: @dalmTo check my code posted in my question i am getting all the data in both functions.

Comment: You said it was stored in the database?  When that code runs you need to get the refresh token populate the client with it or login with a user via a web browser.

Comment: just debugged `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());` not refreshing accessToken.

Comment: because $client->getRefreshToken() is null you need a refresh token first. Assign one.

Comment: `$client->getRefreshToken();` not empty returning value exactly stored in database.